# I am getting the error "actual and formal argument lists differ in length" even though I have a constructor with 3 double parameters

Tags: java, arrays

Question: I am getting the error below even though I have a constructor in Box.java with three parameters.

```
BoxTest.java:19: error: constructor Box in class Box cannot be applied to given types;
        Box box1 = new Box(length, width, height);
                   ^
  required: no arguments
  found: double,double,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Assignment: Create a Box class with the following:

- instance variables length, width, and height
- a no-argument Box constructor — use 1.0 as the default value for width, length and height.
- a Box constructor with three parameters.  There can be NO zero or negative value for the instance variables.  Use 1.0 as the default value for width, length or height if a parameter is invalid.
- get and set (accessor and mutator) methods for each instance variable.  There can be NO zero or negative values for the instance variables so be sure to validate the parameter in the set methods.  Do NOT update the instance variable if the parameter is invalid (zero or negative).  Do NOT use exception handling.
- a toString method that returns a String with the length, width and height, clearly labeled.  Format each value to two places past the decimal point.
- a calculateArea method that calculates and returns the surface area of the box (all 6 sides)
- a calculateVolume method that calculates and returns the volume of the box

Create a BoxTest program with the following.

- an array named boxes that has size (length) 4
- 4 Box objects - place each Box in the array. One Box object must be created with user input for the length, width and height. One Box object must be created with the no-argument constructor. The other Boxes should be created with literal values (2, 3.5, 5.75, etc.).
- use an enhanced for loop to display the length, width, height, area and volume of each Box object, clearly labeled. Do this by calling the appropriate methods. Call the toString method for the length, width and height. Format the area and volume to two places past the decimal point.

BoxTest.java

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BoxTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter length: ");
        double length = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter width: ");
        double width = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter heigth: ");
        double height = input.nextDouble();

        Box[] boxes = new Box[4];

        Box box1 = new Box(length, width, height);
        boxes[0] = box1;

        Box box2 = new Box();
        boxes[1] = box2;

        Box box3 = new Box(2.0, 3.5, 5.75);
        boxes[2] = box3;

        Box box4 = new Box(9.0, 12.0, 15.0);
        boxes[3] = box4;

        System.out.println(displayBox(box1));
    }

    private static String displayBox(Box box)
    {
        System.out.print(box.toString());
    }
}
```

Box.java

```
public class Box
{
    // Instance variables
    private double length;
    private double width;
    private double height;

    // ********************* DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR *******
    public Box()
    {
        this(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }

    // ********************* CONSTRUCTOR *******
    public Box(double length, double width, double height)
    {
        if(length > 0)
        {
            this.length = length;
        }
        else
        {
            this.length = 1.0;
        }


        if(width > 0)
        {
            this.width = width;
        }
        else
        {
            this.width = 1.0;
        }


        if(height > 0)
        {
            this.height = height;
        }
        else
        {
            this.height = 1.0;
        }
    }

    public double getLength()
    {
        return length;
    }

    public double getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }

    public double getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    public void setLength(double length)
    {
        if(length > 0)
        {
            this.length = length;
        }
    }

    public void setWidth(double width)
    {
        if(width > 0)
        {
            this.width = width;
        }
    }

    public void setHeight(double height)
    {
        if(height > 0)
        {
            this.height = height;
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%s = %.2f%n%s = %.2f%n%s = %.2f%n", "Length", length, "Width", width, "Height", height);
    }

    public double calculateArea(double length, double width, double height)
    {
        double area = 2 * (length * width) + 2 * (height * width) + 2 * (length * height);
        return area;
    }

    public double calculateVolume(double length, double width, double height)
    {
        double volume = length * width * height;
        return volume;
    }
}
```

Error:

---

```
BoxTest.java:19: error: constructor Box in class Box cannot be applied to given types;
        Box box1 = new Box(length, width, height);
                   ^
  required: no arguments
  found: double,double,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

BoxTest.java:25: error: constructor Box in class Box cannot be applied to given types;
        Box box3 = new Box(2.0, 3.5, 5.75);
                   ^
  required: no arguments
  found: double,double,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

BoxTest.java:28: error: constructor Box in class Box cannot be applied to given types;
        Box box4 = new Box(9.0, 12.0, 15.0);
                   ^
  required: no arguments
  found: double,double,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
                                         ^
3 errors
```

Comment: Re-compile Box perhaps.

Comment: For your last error at least, `displayBox` already prints, and returns nothing. You can't try to print the return of that method, since it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thank you very much, Carcigenicate. When I changed from void to String, I dont get the last error any more.

private static String displayBox(Box box)
 {
  System.out.print(box.toString());
 }

Comment: In your Box class, whats with those stars at the end of last conditional: if(height > 0)
        {
            this.height = height;
        }
        else
        {
            this.height = 1.0;
        }**

Comment: @Fair Play: I was trying to bold those lines. I have removed those stars now.

Comment: BoxTest.displayBox needs to either be void and the System.out.println should be removed, or displayBox should not itself call println but instead should return the value.

Other than that, the code works fine for me.

Comment: @EricWessel That code shouldn't even compile. You should either return a string, and not print in `displayBox`, or print in `displayBox`, return nothing, and don't try to print the return of `displayBox`. If that code actually compiles, something exceedingly screwy is going on with your IDE. I'd run the "clean" routine in your IDE. It seems like you have old files kicking around interfering with stuff.

Comment: @TrentonD.Adams 
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_144

Comment: My suggestion would be to use an IDE. It will be highlight your compilation errors before you attempt to run your code

Comment: If you want an enhanced for loop, use `private static void displayBoxes(Box[] boxes)`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels & Trenton D. Adams: Thank you very much. It seems like I didn't save Box.java. I saved it again and ran no errors now. I had compiled using javac *.java.

Comment: This question should be deleted as it is non-reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BoxTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter length: ");
        double length = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter width: ");
        double width = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter heigth: ");
        double height = input.nextDouble();

        Box[] boxes = new Box[4];

        Box box1 = new Box(length, width, height);
        boxes[0] = box1;

        Box box2 = new Box();
        boxes[1] = box2;

        Box box3 = new Box(2.0, 3.5, 5.75);
        boxes[2] = box3;

        Box box4 = new Box(9.0, 12.0, 15.0);
        boxes[3] = box4;

        System.out.println(box1);
    }
}
```

Make sure you've recompiled Box.java since you last changed it.  And there's no need for a "displayBox" method, as box1 has a toString.